# How to always add prefix to url in Node.js request

Tags: node.js, request

I'm using the package "request" (https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) in Node.js. What I want to have is somehow like the "defaults" api, that I give a default url prefix to the request object, the url of any request which sent from my request object will be prefixed before sending. Is that possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use request.defaults

```
const request = require('request');

const baseRequest = request.defaults({baseUrl : 'https://example.com/api/'}})
```

now use baseRequest object

Documentation Link-
[Request.defaults](https://github.com/request/request#requestdefaultsoptions)

Comment: This is the right answer but could be improved with a link to the docs for request.defaults

Comment: Thanks. here is the link 
https://github.com/request/request#requestdefaultsoptions

Comment: It would be best to edit your answer to include the link so people don't need to look in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a default request instance, in there config you baseUrl

```
    var request = require('request');

    var r = request.defaults({
      baseUrl: 'https://example.com/api/',
    })

    r({
      'url':'/end/point?test=true',
      'method': "GET",
    },function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
      }
    }); // will fetch https://example.com/api/end/point?test=true
```